# How to avoid TimeoutError error when connecting to FTP from Azure Function

Tags: python, azure, ftp, azure-functions, ftplib

I have written a python module using the package `ftplib` to retrieve data from my data provider that does the following:

1) Upload a text file in a FTP server using the STOR command.

2) Every minute, retrieve full list of files in a FTP server 
   directory. If this list satisfies certain conditions, go to the 
   next step. Repeat this step otherwise.

3) Download all files from a FTP server directory using the RETR command.

I have been running the previous process in a VM for several months without any issue. I've recently decided to move the process in a different cloud environment (Azure Functions - App service plan) in order to reduce the maintenance costs but I've started to get serious error message with step 3 exclusively (steps 1 and 2 work always perfectly).

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the 
connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or 
established connection failed because connected host has failed to 
respond
```

ATTEMPTS:

- The error tends to happen only when it takes more than 15 minutes or so to run step 2. For this reason, the problem should not be related to closed ports/firewall.
- I've verified with the data provider and they told me that the problem is not on their side, so the problem is related with the azure function.
- During step 2, I've tried to send a NOOP message to the FTP and to download a small file from the FTP every minute to keep the connection alive. However, I still get the same error message after a while or when jumping to step 3.
- When I use an active FTP connection, I still get a (different) error message: `ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`
- Close and reopen the FTP connection for every iteration of step 2.

I have a very strong feeling that even if Azure Functions with the App Service Plan are not supposed to have the 10 minutes timeout of the Consumption Plan, something behind the scenes in Azure still doesn't like long running processes (~30 minutes).

Comment: I tried to reproducing your issue but failed.According to your attempts,you said you tried to download a small file but still get the same error. I thought your python script was blocked by server. Would you please to post your entire python script in your azure function to let me help you?

Comment: By the way, what location do you want store the files downloaded from ftp directory? Local ? Azure Storage? Or where?

Comment: Files are downloaded withing the Azure Function. It turns out that the problem was related with the download of a large .csv of ~100MB. In addition I was using the function app to run multiple instance at the same time on a schedule, so there was a resource exhaustion problem that was making things even worse. However, I'm still don't know if there is some unknown timeout threshold to download large files.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices: "Avoid long running functions. Large, long-running functions can cause unexpected timeout issues" 

Are you using Consumption Plan or App Service Plan? In Consumption there is a max 10 minute timeout.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale

Comment: As mentioned in the questions, I'm using an App Service Plan that is not supposed to run function without time constraints.